# Javascript "catch" out of memory error

Tags: javascript

I am developing a serverside Javascript application (using our own engine). Now I need to test the application until I get an out of memory error. In Java you can try/catch this error since there it is an exception. I could not try/catch it in Javascript. Is there any way to continue execution after the error is thrown?

Comment: I don't think so. Honestly, catching it in Java is asking for trouble too. When you're Out of Memory how do you intend to recover?

Comment: Well Java does it for you so I thought there might be a way in Javascript ;-) but I suspected there is none.

Comment: Java [does not recover](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37335/2970947) from OOM for you. There's a reason it's a runtime error.

Comment: Since your make your own engine, you can just throw the error on allocations, but the problem is that, handling it in try/catch might cause further allocations and your app will crash eventually.

Comment: And the point is not to recover but rather output something afterwards. But I guess I can output beforehand and just wait till it fails!

Comment: @eclipse Will this [nodejs out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357339/nodejs-out-of-memory) help?

Answer (score 0):

This is in the browser and relates to the stack rather than memory, but consider:

```
try { (function foo() { return foo(); }()) } 
catch(e) { console.log("error is", e); }
```

Output is

```
error is RangeError {stack: (...), message: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"}
```