# Is there any solution that will allow me to process this many characters into a string with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory

**My question:**

Is there any solution that will allow me to process this many characters into a string with Node.js?

**The problem:**

I need to compute a huge (array, and then) string of character combinations in Node.js, like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var legalChars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 
'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
'8', '9', '_'];

var fiveChars = [legalChars, 
    legalChars, 
    legalChars, 
    legalChars, 
    legalChars];

//output all possible combinations of the arrays within
//fiveChars
function allPossibleCases(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
    } else if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        var result = [];
        var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
        // recur with the rest of array
        for (var c in allCasesOfRest) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
                result.push(arr[0][i] + allCasesOfRest[c]);
                var val = arr[0][i] + allCasesOfRest[c];
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }
}

// join array of results into string
var result = allPossibleCases(fiveChars).join('", "');

// this essentially writes the string in the form of a Node module 
//containing a giant array
fs.writeFile("./data/fiveChars.js", 
'fiveChar = ["' + result + '"]; \r\n module.exports = fiveChar;',
function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

I want to continue adding character rows up to 16 rows:

```
var sixteenChars = [legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars, legalChars];
```

The problem is that Node cant cope with this all at once.

> FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory Aborted

---

I don't want to **[download more RAM](http://www.downloadmoreram.com/),** just looking for a way to handle this calculation process over time rather than filling the memory allocation up.

Comment: Perhaps you need to increase the heap size that NodeJS uses (via the V8 engine)? They're from a little while ago, but here's a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8) and a [blog post](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/).

Comment: When does the out-of-memory problem happen? If you can create the `result` array successfully, you can create a writeable stream and output it to a file in pieces. If you can't make the complete array, then that's a bit trickier.

Comment: @apsillers good point. I'll update my question with that info.

Comment: @ajp15243 the heap size increase will probably not cover 16 digits combos, this error is happening with just five of them

Comment: you do too much work to get your shorter-than-maximum combos. if you have all 5 char combos, you can simply slice one char off each to get every possible 4 char combo. you will have duplicates of course, but depending on order, you might be able to just calc the # of 4char combos, pull that many off the 5char set, then slice them all down by one to get all your 4char combos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I like using [`highland`](http://highlandjs.org/) these days, I thought I'd post a solution here as an exercise, that I think should scale memory-wise to a lot of combinations. It might be too slow for you I don't know because what you want to generate is 37^16 combinations which is a lot.

This solution will create a file containing all solutions separated by a new line for the 5 chars case. Maybe you can try it and see if it fits your box ;-). Going to the 16 chars case will just need adding new flatMap calls.

Keep me posted ! you can `tail -f` the file to see it growing.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('highland');

var legalChars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
'8', '9', '_'];


var suffixer = function(alphabet) {
  var len = alphabet.length;
  return function(prefix) {
    var i = 0;
    return _(function(push, next) {
      if (i == len) {
        push(null, _.nil);
      } else {
        push(null, prefix + alphabet[i]);
        i++;
      }
      next();
    })
  }
}

var s = _(['\n'])
        .flatMap(suffixer(legalChars))
        .flatMap(suffixer(legalChars))
        .flatMap(suffixer(legalChars))
        .flatMap(suffixer(legalChars))
        .flatMap(suffixer(legalChars))

s.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('alpha.txt'));
```

Now why you would want to generate so many combinations is another question !

Comment: Running this for a test now. Thank you first off, for your help and the introduction to highland.

Comment: Yes, this works great. I'm studying the highland library to modify and get speed / remaining time feedback, but yes this is the perfect solution. It may sacrifice some speed, but it can handle any size over time and that's exactly what I was looking for.