# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been running a nodejs program in my machine. The program ran for 4 hours and after that it showed 
  `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory`. I have seen the other questions in the forum where they have asked the same question, but the answers provided are not clear.

I am using a machine of 8GB RAM, 500 GB storage space. Please do help me on this. I need an exact answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [memory limit in Node.js (and chrome V8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8)

Comment: Actually that answer was 3 years old. Most probably the nodejs people have tried to fix that. or there might be some other solution. I have checked that solution and I didn't find that convincing. I hope you understand this.