# Task Runners (Gulp, Grunt, etc) and Bundlers (Webpack, Browserify). Why use together?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, bundler, browserify, webpack

I am trying to learn about technologies including Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, Browserify, but I did not feel that there is much difference between them.

In other words, I feel Webpack can do everything that a task runner does. But still I got a huge examples where gulp and webpack are used together. What's the reason?

I might be taking things in the wrong direction. Am I missing anything? If so, what?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

[Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) are actually task runners, and they have differences like config driven tasks versus stream based transformations.  Each has its own strengths and weaknesses, but at the end of the day, they pretty much help you create tasks that can be run to solve a larger build problem. Most of the time, they have nothing to do with the actual run-time of the app, but rather they transform or they put files, configs and other things in place so that the run time works as expected.  Sometimes they even spawn servers or other processes that you need to run your app.

[Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) are package bundlers.  Basically, they are designed to run through all of a package's dependencies and concatenate their source into one file that (ideally) can be used in a browser.  They are important to modern web development, because we use so many libraries that are designed to run with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [v8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) compiler.  Again, there are pros and cons and different reasons some developers prefer one or the other (or sometimes both!).  Usually the output bundles of these solutions contain some sort of bootstrapping mechanisms to help you get to the right file or module in a potentially huge bundle.

The blurred line between runners and bundlers might be that bundlers can also do complex transformations or [trans-pilations](https://babeljs.io/) during their run-time, so they can do several things that task runners can do.  In fact, between browserify and webpack there's probably around a hundred [transformers](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms) that you can use to modify your source code.  For comparison, there's at least 2000 gulp plugins listed on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gulpplugin) right now.  So you can see that there are clear (hopefully... ;)) definitions of what works best for your application.

That being said, you might see a complex project actually using both task-runners and package bundlers at the same time or in tandem.  For example at my office, we use gulp to start our project, and webpack is actually run from a specific gulp task that creates the source bundles that we need to run our app in the browser.  And because our app is [isomorphic](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/react-to-the-future-with-isomorphic-apps/), we also [bundle some of the server](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) code.

In my humble opinion, you might want to get familiar with all of these technologies because chances are you will see (use) all them in the course of your career.

Comment: One of the best answers on SO I've ever read and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Maybe write up into a blog post?

Comment: Well here you can get pretty good explanation - https://survivejs.com/webpack/appendices/comparison/

Answer (score 0):

I've just created my own task runner/bundler.

It's simpler to use than gulp and probably webpack (although I've never used webpack).

It's very simple and has babel, browserify, uglify, minify, and handlebars out of the box.

The syntax looks like this:

```js
const Autumn = require("autumn-wizard");




const w = new Autumn();

//----------------------------------------
// CSS
//----------------------------------------
var cssFiles = [
    './lib/pluginABC/src/css/**/*.{css,scss}',
];
w.forEach(cssFiles, srcPath => {
    var dstPath = w.replace('/src/', '/dist/', srcPath);
    dstPath = w.replace('.scss', '.css', dstPath);
    dstPath = w.replace('.css', '.min.css', dstPath);
    w.minify(srcPath, dstPath, {
        sourceMap: useSourceMap,
    });
});


//----------------------------------------
// BUNDLE THE JS MODULE
//----------------------------------------
var srcPath = "./lib/pluginABC/src/main.js";
var dstPath = "./lib/pluginABC/dist/bundled.min.js";
w.bundle(srcPath, dstPath, {
    debug: useSourceMap,
});


//----------------------------------------
// CREATE THE HANDLEBARS TEMPLATES
//----------------------------------------
var tplPaths = [
    "./lib/pluginABC/src/templates/**/*.hbs",
];
dstPath = "./lib/pluginABC/dist/templates/bundled.js";
w.precompile(tplPaths, dstPath);
```

And the doc is here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/Autumn

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Ling: I use classes and "import" all the time. Does your project transpile imported files?