# javascript file that loads node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to include a single javascript file in a page, which in turn loads 1 or many node modules from an external source? that means it loads all JS and/or CSS files in that node module.

To say it in another way, I'd like users to include a single javascript file in their project, and that javascript file requires node modules to function. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using `browserify`?

Comment: When you talk about node modules but in the same breath talk about css files you confuse me. Are these files supposed to be loaded within the browser client side?

Comment: @Darkrum i'm trying to to use [Shepherd](https://github.com/HubSpot/shepherd) which creates DOM elements with its own CSS that gets installed with `npm` and comes part of the `node_modules` package.

Comment: you can create a npm package, and tell them to add your package to their project dependencies

Comment: @guest271314 this seems to fit the bill, but will it allow me to load external modules that are not installed in the end user's machine?

Comment: @ssbb This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. if I know the devs on the project I have, they'll take a month to do anything more than adding a single tag to their HTML.

Comment: @ssbb also, I would like to be able to change the referenced code at my end.

Comment: _"but will it allow me to load external modules that are not installed in the end user's machine?"_ What do you mean?

Comment: @guest271314 meaning can I use browserify to require modules that are not part of the end user's environment? in other words, let's say whoever installs the script doesn't even have node installed, and I require a module, will that module run?

Comment: @Abdul See [What is the difference between browserify/requirejs modules and ES6 modules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28674652/) , [Task Runners (Gulp, Grunt, etc) and Bundlers (Webpack, Browserify). Why use together?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33561272/) _"Webpack and Browserify are package bundlers. Basically, they are designed to run through all of a package's dependencies and concatenate their source into one file that (ideally) can be used in a browser."_

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for your help! I've got some education to do now.