# Getting GC, process out of memory error while bundling via webpack

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, webpack, babeljs

Getting following error when bundling my project with webpack.
When I have only a few chunk (split) points (require.ensure ones) then it runs okay, but when I increase the split points following error comes.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  124541 ms: Mark-sweep 1379.0 (1457.1) -> 1378.9 (1457.1) MB, 891.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  125398 ms: Mark-sweep 1378.9 (1457.1) -> 1378.9 (1457.1) MB, 857.0 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  126289 ms: Mark-sweep 1378.9 (1457.1) -> 1378.9 (1457.1) MB, 890.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  127136 ms: Mark-sweep 1378.9 (1457.1) -> 1378.9 (1457.1) MB, 847.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x18342c237339 <JS Object>
    1: get [/path/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:~75] [pc=0x126413012f98] (this=0x30cb87230cc1 <JS Function NodePath (SharedFunctionInfo 0xa7d7f38b8d9)>,_ref2=0x2b8f0305a311 <an Object with map 0x365041d49801>)
    2: node [/path/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:~119] [pc=0x126412dd40f5] (...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works when I'm increasing size of node, by default it's around 1GB (not sure exact)

Running node by increasing it's memory via `--max_old_space_size=4092`, it works

Source:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1875#issuecomment-170663572

Comment: This works, but only to a certain extent. Even with it set to 4092, I still get the error, just not as often. The big problem I have found with doing this is that it uses a ton of resources and causes the computer to freeze fairly regular.

Comment: check in webpack@4 - same issue?

Comment: For my teams particular issue it turned out to be a memory leak with the Hot Module Replacement Plugin. I tried upgrading to Webpack 4 in the hopes that fixed it, but it did not. The only solution was to disable it. Since then our team hasn't had the issue.

Comment: @MichaelS. I have the problem reversed, upgrading to Webpack 4 introduced the problem. Have you found anything that works better than increasing the space size?

Comment: @NikSo Can you once check with disabling uglification in prod builds?

Comment: @AbhinavSingi, so I uglification on for prod builds and it never gave me problems. My out of memory is when I run a react hot reload server, the one that preserved react's state; not the one that comes with webpack

Comment: @NikSo Unfortunately the best option was to disable it for our situation. Turning it off hasn't caused us any problems, and has made our entire team much happier to not have it crash all the time.

Comment: @MichaelS. F5'ing makes me sad :( Will keep digging and write if I find anything. Good luck!

Comment: this is still an issue in latest Webpack.. Webpack makes me sad