# webpack exception Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, webpack, garbage-collection

The project is Angular4 project.
Few minutes after running build with webpack, we get an exception, memory goes about 1.5-2.0GB, something is 
causing a memory leak, but not sure what?
Here's the exeption:

> <--- Last few GCs ---
>
> 553384 ms: Mark-sweep 1018.2 (1435.7) -> 1017.8 (1433.7) MB, 1002.1 / 0.1 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>     554060 ms: Mark-sweep 1017.8 (1433.7) -> 1017.7 (1445.7) MB, 676.4 / 0.1 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>     554889 ms: Mark-sweep 1017.7 (1445.7) -> 1028.3 (1379.7) MB, 827.9 / 0.1 ms [last resort gc].
>     555690 ms: Mark-sweep 1028.3 (1379.7) -> 1028.3 (1345.7) MB, 801.3 / 0.1 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 000000330513FA99 
>       1: update [crypto.js:74] [pc=000002D7B9D55EB9] (this=000000AD941B45C9 ,data=000000AD941B45A1 ,encoding=0000003305177181 )
>       2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
>       3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [C:\Users\yonid\Desktop\soc3d\ui\node_modules\inspectpack\lib\utils\hash.js:20] [pc=000002D7BA07EFE8] (this...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GC, process out of memory error while bundling via webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727743/getting-gc-process-out-of-memory-error-while-bundling-via-webpack)