# How do I build a JSON file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'd like to assemble a `manifest.json` file, as used by Chrome extensions, in a "smarter," programmatic sort of way. I'm using npm for my dependency resolution, and its `package.json` includes some shared fields with the `manifest.json` file, including "name," "description," and "version."

Is there a way to define something like a partial `manifest.json` file which includes all the Chrome-specific stuff, but fill in shared values where appropriate? I've found that this is pretty straightforward in Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var jeditor = require('gulp-json-editor');

gulp.task('manifest', function() {
    var pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
    gulp.src('./manifest.json')
      .pipe(jeditor({
        'name': pkg.name,
        'description': pkg.description,
        'version': pkg.version,
        'author': pkg.author,
        'homepage_url': pkg.homepage,
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

Even if there's some npm package out there designed for this purpose, can someone explain to me how something like this might be done generally? I know Webpack 2 has a built-in json loader, but I'm not clear how it would be used in a case like this.

Comment: How funny - I have the exact same problem and I googled "webpack write json file" and this post came up! Thanks :)

Comment: me too, landed on this page looking for "webpack convert js to json" whil actually checking very same problem )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credit to Sean Larkin from the Webpack project for reaching out to me and helping me figure out how to get this done. I needed to create a custom loader to handle reading the existing `manifest.json` and adding my fields of interest to it.

```
// File: src/manifest-loader.js

const fs = require('fs');

// A loader to transform a partial manifest.json file into a complete
// manifest.json file by adding entries from an NPM package.json.
module.exports = function(source) {
  const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
  const merged = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(source), {
    'name': pkg.name,
    'description': pkg.description,
    'version': pkg.version,
    'author': pkg.author,
    'homepage_url': pkg.homepage,
  });
  const mergedJson = JSON.stringify(merged);
  // In Webpack, loaders ultimately produce JavaScript. In order to produce
  // another file type (like JSON), it needs to be emitted separately.
  this.emitFile('manifest.json', mergedJson);
  // Return the processed JSON to be used by the next item in the loader chain.
  return mergedJson;
};
```

Then configure webpack to use my custom `manifest-loader`.

```
// File: webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // Tell Webpack where to find our custom loader (in the "src" directory).
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
  },

  // The path to the incomplete manifest.json file.
  entry: "./manifest.json",
  output: {
    // Where the newly built manifest.json will go.
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // This file probably won't actually be used by anything.
    filename: "manifest.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Only apply these loaders to manifest.json.
        test: /manifest.json$/,
        // Loaders are applied in reverse order.
        use: [
          // Second: JSON -> JS
          "json-loader",
          // First: partial manifest.json -> complete manifest.json
          "manifest-loader",
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The result, when running Webpack, is a `dist/` directory containing `manifest.js` and `manifest.json`, with `manifest.json` containing everything from the original, top-level `manifest.json` plus the additional info from `package.json`. The extra `manifest.js` is a script that exposes the contents of `manifest.json` to any other JavaScript in the project that wants it. This is probably not too useful, but a Chrome extension might conceivably want to `require` this in a script somewhere to expose some of this information in a friendly way.

Comment: its fixed? or you can try webpack with gulp if you want http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html so you can use this package `gulp-json-editor` if u want.

Comment: @RahmatAligos Thanks, but my goal was to simplify my build process so that I would not have to use both Gulp and Webpack. This was one of the few issues preventing me from switching, and the custom loader solution here solves my problem.

Comment: This is a great solution!  I used file-loader instead of json-loader so I don't get manifest.js and made a few other tweaks: https://gist.github.com/bronson/163d7d4dde2a845ea3d6af3a0d86d174  Huge thanks for answering your own question.

Comment: @bronson I'm glad it helped someone else. I noticed a comment on your gist about needing to import manifest.json to make your solution work, and I think I know the fix: name "manifest.json" as one of your entry points in your webpack config.

Comment: Yes, putting 'manifest.json' as an entrypoint creates the manifest.json file, but it also creates manifest.bundle.js.  (couldn't find any way around this)  I figured placing an import in my topmost js file was less weird than having an unused file end up in my build.  It's a matter of taste I suppose.  :)

Answer (score 69):

There is actually a more elegant solution than the one by @user108471 (although it is inspired by it), and that is to use the [`copy-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). With its [`transform`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#transform) ability, you can add the desired values to the `manifest.json` on the fly before copying it to its destination.

It has two advantages:

- it doesn't generate an extra unnecessary `manifest.js`-bundle ([@bronson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457948/7770056) also fixes this)
- you don't need to `require` the `manifest.json` in some other `.js`-file (which would seem semantically backwards to me)

A minimal setup could be this:

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
// you can just require .json, saves the 'fs'-hassle
let package = require('./package.json');

function modify(buffer) {
   // copy-webpack-plugin passes a buffer
   var manifest = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());

   // make any modifications you like, such as
   manifest.version = package.version;

   // pretty print to JSON with two spaces
   manifest_JSON = JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2);
   return manifest_JSON;
}


module.exports = {

   // ...

   plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
         {
            from: "./src/manifest.json",
            to:   "./dist/manifest.json",
            transform (content, path) {
                return modify(content)
            }
         }])
   ]

}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I actually do like having the manifest.js available for some convenient in-app reporting, but this is definitely the more direct solution. I'd actually be curious to dig into the plugin and find out how it works, since enough people had the same specific manifest.json need that it might justify a plugin just to handle this specific case.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the solution I needed. +1

Comment: This is cool, just want to note that I received an obscure error apparently on the toString() line when I used a babel config via `webpack.config.babel.js`. The error was "Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es.object.to-string'" and my solution was to remove `.babel` from the config file name =)

Comment: I don't know what data aggregating website this is, but I found this answer [here](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50993589.html) before finding it on SO

Comment: @Luminous thanks, I sent them a message asking them to add proper attribution per the CC BY-SA license.

Answer (score 3):

My solution in Webpack 4 below. It's a generic solution for generating json files using Webpack loaders, but it works well for manifest.json files as well.

#### webpack.config.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const resolve = require("path").resolve;

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        entry: resolve(__dirname, "app/main.js"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /manifest\.js$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: []  // Empty array on purpose.
                })
            }
        ],
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    context: resolve(__dirname, "app"),
                    name: "[path][name].[ext]",
                    publicPath: "/",
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["npm_package_version"]),  // automagically populated by webpack, available as process.env.npm_package_version in loaded files.
        new ExtractTextPlugin("manifest.json"),
    ]
};
```

#### app/main.js

```
const manifest = require('./manifest.js');

// Other parts of app …
```

#### app/manifest.js

```
const icon = require('./icon.png');  

const manifestData = {  
    icon: {"128": icon},  // icon.png will be in the emitted files, yay!
    version: process.env.npm_package_version,  // See webpack.config.js plugins
    // other manifest data …
};

// Whatever string you output here will be emitted as manifest.json:
module.exports = JSON.stringify(manifestData, null, 2);
```

#### package.json dependencies

```
{
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "webpack": "4.12.0",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const manifest = {
  entry: './src/chrome_extension/dummy_index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'DELETED.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: 'LICENSE.md'},
        {from: 'assets/img/icon.png', to: `${ASSETS_PATH}/icon.png`},
        {from: 'src/chrome_extension/manifest.json',
          transform: function(manifestBuffer, path) {
            const manifestString = manifestBuffer.toString()
                .replace(/\$\{OPTIONS_PAGE_PATH\}/g, OPTIONS_PAGE_PATH)
                .replace(/\$\{CONTENT_SCRIPT_PATH\}/g, CONTENT_SCRIPT_PATH)
                .replace(/\$\{ASSETS_PATH\}/g, ASSETS_PATH);
            return Buffer.from(manifestString);
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    new RemoveFilesWebpackPlugin({
      after: {
        log: false,
        include: [
          'dist/DELETED.js',
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  stats: 'none',
  mode: 'none',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using your script enough that I published a somewhat modified version of it on NPM: https://github.com/bronson/manifest-package-loader

Hope it's as easy as `yarn add -D manifest-package-loader` and updating your webpack.config.js.

Coincidentally, just this morning I ran across chem-loader, which might also work: https://github.com/mrmisterman/chem-loader

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack 4, its pretty simple. We dont need to specify any explicit json loaders

Note: I am just bundling everything into a single html file here, but you get the idea that there is no json loader in webpack.config.js file

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
 const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');

module.exports = {
 module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }],
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
  },
  {
      test: /\.ico$/,
      use: ["file-loader"]
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "html-loader",
        options: { minimize: true }
      }
    ]
  }
],
},
 plugins: [
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html",
  inlineSource: '.(js|css)$'
}),
new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(),
],
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  }
}
```

In my app.js I just use

```
import data from './data/data.json'
```