# Use webpack plugins without 'entry' index.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack to assemble dist directories with environment-specific configs (`manifest.json`) and file structures

My issue is that webpack wants me to have an empty `src/index.js` file

In certain environments, the compilation happens after I've assembled the `/dist` folder, zipped, and uploaded to their service.

Is there any way to avoid `index.js` and just run `CopyWebpackPlugin`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking into using `manifest.json` or `manifest.js` as the entry for this build, since this file is the connection between an options HTML app, a browser content script, icon.png, etc

Both `CleanWebpackPlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin` have given me tons of problems, and it seems that using loaders may be the correct, pure, synchronous way to go

[My current inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249538/1487102) uses a simple `module.exports` with `arguments[0]` [source from the previous loader](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse) to easily transform the source

---

I did come up with a hack (un-maintanable) solution to delete the unused file afterwards, which may be of use to someone.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'manifest',
  entry: {
    manifest: './src/manifest.json',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'DELETED.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: './src/manifest.json'},
        {from: './assets/images/icon.png'},
      ],
    }),
    new RemoveFilesWebpackPlugin({
      before: {
        log: false,
        include: [
          'dist',
        ],
      },
      after: {
        log: false,
        include: [
          'dist/DELETED.js',
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  mode: 'none',
}
```

The problem with this idea is that `manifest.json` is not being used to gather it's own assets -- the assets are declared in this bundler's config.

---

I have two additional `webpack.config.js` files for

1. generating an HTML options page using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`
2. bundling the main script

but as mentioned, maintenance requires digging in the build file, rather than just editing source and requiring relative paths