# Copy array --> stack or heap overflow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, heap-memory

I have an array named `globalArrayAllTrades` as you see below. I simply like to INVERT the date in a new copy of the array. So I loop through, create a new object and add it to the new array - simple.

Then function does exactly as expected. BUT if the array contains too many objects the code fails with a "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory".

My laptop has 8 GB of memory...When the NODEJS process crashes it uses about 1.5 GB and about 70% of of totally amount of available memory is used.

I do run the NODEJS app with the parameter: `--max_old_space_size=5000` which normally fixes every thing. But not this one and i have tried MANY different ways to code the same function - BUT each and every time - it fails...unless the original array is smaller.

How can I fix this issue?

```
 function invertTrades(){

     var original = globalArrayAllTrades.slice();

     globalArrayAllTrades.length = 0;
     globalListAllTrades.length = 0;

     for(var i = 0; i < original.length; i++){

         var objS = original[i];
         var objE = original[original.length-1-i];
         var objInv = new TradePoint(objS.number, objS.matchdate, objE.price, objE.size, objE.issell);

         globalArrayAllTrades.push(objInv);

         globalListAllTrades[objInv.matchdate] = objInv;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This may answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8

Comment: @Simon That question is 5 years old. One of the answers says that the memory limit has been removed.

Comment: What is `globalListAllTrades`? It seems like you're using it as a key-value-store (object), so `.length = 0` will hardly empty it.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, that doesn't do anything, but I don't think it matters. He's replacing all the entries with `globalListAllTrades[objInv.matchdate] = objInv`.

Comment: Does the `TradePoint` constructor have any side effects? Why are you making that `original` copy? Where is `globalArrayAllTrades` declared? How large is it (what is `original.length`)?

Comment: He's making a copy of the array because he modifies the array with `globalArrayAllTrades.push()`

Comment: Nope. I have been running node app. using about 200 GB (YES GB) on big Amazon servers with the option set to  --max_old_space_size=200000 without any problems... But it seems like this is not about the total amount of used memory... but more like the size of the heap or stack... but i cant change these... or the parameters to do so - doesnt change any thing...

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I was going to suggest an algorithm that doesn't need the copy if there's no other reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save some memory by making original just contain the properties you need to invert, not the whole `TradePoint` object. Then you don't need to construct new `TradePoint` objects, you can modify them in place.

```
var original = globalArrayAllTrades.map(function(trade) {
    return {
        trade.price,
        trade.size,
        trade.issell
    };
}).reverse();
globalArrayAllTrades.forEach(function(trade, i) {
    trade.price = original[i].price;
    trade.size = original[i].size;
    trade.issell = original[i].issell;
});
```

And since all the objects were modified in place, there's no need to update `globalListAllTrades`.

Another way is to swap the `price`, `size`, and `issell` properties in place between the pairs of elements:

```
var midpoint = Math.floor(globalArrayAllTrade.length/2);
for (var i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
    var objS = globalArrayAllTrades[i];
    var objE = globalArrayAllTrades[globalArrayAllTrades.length-1-i];

    var temp = objS.price;
    objS.price = objE.price;
    objE.price = temp;

    temp = objS.size;
    objS.size = objE.size;
    objE.size = temp;

    temp = objS.issell;
    objS.issell = objE.issell;
    objE.issell = temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't know this notation... what is trade? Anyways... i think this solution will use more memory than Bergi's ...and that still fails...

Comment: `trade` is the current element of the array in the `.forEach()` loop.

Comment: I added another solution that doesn't allocate any new memory, it swaps the properties in place.

Comment: The first one - failed.

Comment: Second one. I get your point! But god damn. It still crashes!?

Comment: You must be running into some kind of error in the node.js garbage collector. The second version uses almost no memory.

Comment: There was a typo: `globalArrayAllTrades/2` should be `globalArrayAllTrades.length/2`. Try it with that fix.

Comment: I added the fix. Just to give you a quick response...the app is still running - memory use is still like 1.5 GB...But in increases much slower than ealier...! I will give you a final answer in 5 min...

Comment: The ealier solutions failed with this:Security context: 00000275A24B4639 <JS Object>
    2: ConvertToString(aka ConvertToString) [native array.js:~159] [pc=000002D3FA63B473] (this=00000275A24041B9 <undefined>,O=0000030733085959 <a TradePoint with map 0000025976CB49F1>)
    3: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:138] [pc=000002D3FA6808E0] (this=00000275A24041B9 <undefined>,o=000003FB6E4B3181 <JS Array[1178759]>,v=1178759,C=00000323BCBFF461 <String[1]: ,>,B=00000275A2495299 <JS Fun...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Comment: Your second solution worked! Its peaked like almost 1.5 GB ...and then slowly decreased in size...and got the job done! Thank you SO much! I guess it is the globalArrayAllTrades itself which uses all 1.5 GB of memory - NO matter - if data is inverted or not! But IF extra memory is use due to extra logic - the app. simply crashes. FYI: The array contains 1.2 million objects.

Comment: BTW: How do i monitor my app and the resources it uses etc.?

Comment: On Unix one of the most basic tools is `top`. There may be similar GUI tools.

Comment: you have a link? its not NPM Top...apparently? What about a windows tool?

Comment: It's not part of node.js, just a general-purpose Unix command for monitoring the resource usage of processes. Just type "top" in a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just doing this?

```
// Copy array and then reverse it
var newArray = [].concat(original).reverse();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: he's not just reversing the array. He's combining properties of the objects opposite each other in the array. Look at `objInv`.

Comment: Its NOT ALL properties in the array i like to change! The date must be the same - but price and the rest - must be "invert".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding to copy that array:

```
function getInverse(i) {
    var objS = globalArrayAllTrades[i];
    var objE = globalArrayAllTrades[globalArrayAllTrades.length-1-i];
    var objInv = new TradePoint(objS.number, objS.matchdate, objE.price, objE.size, objE.issell);
    globalListAllTrades[objInv.matchdate] = objInv;
    return objInv;
}
function invertTrades(){
     globalListAllTrades.length = 0;
     for (var i = 0, l = Math.floor(globalArrayAllTrades.length/2); i < l; i++) {
         var j = globalArrayAllTrades.length-1-i;
         var a = getInverse(i);
         var b = getInverse(j);
         globalArrayAllTrades[i] = a;
         globalArrayAllTrades[j] = b;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Really nice try! Smart. But i must disappoint you. It still crashes.

Comment: `globalArrayAllTrades/2` should be `globalArrayAllTrades.length/2`

Comment: Hmm, that won't work because you set `globalListAllTrades.length = 0` on the line before. You need to get the midpoint before you do that.

Comment: @Barmar That's `globalList…` not `globalArray…`. It might be omitted nonetheless, though.