# Node.js process hangs when creating huge object

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a node process that I use to add key-values to an object.  When I get to about 9.88 million keys added, the process appears to hang.  I assumed an out-of-memory issue, so I turned on `trace_gc` and also put in a check in the the code that adds the keys:

```
const { heapTotal, heapUsed } = process.memoryUsage()
if ((heapUsed / heapTotal) > 0.99) {
  throw new Error('Too much memory')
}
```

That condition was never met, and the error never thrown.  As far as `--trace_gc` output, my last scavenge log was:

```
[21544:0x104000000]  2153122 ms: Scavenge 830.0 (889.8) -> 814.3 (889.8) MB, 1.0 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
```

Mark-sweep, however, continues logging this:

```
[21544:0x104000000]  3472253 ms: Mark-sweep 1261.7 (1326.9) -> 813.4 (878.8) MB, 92.3 / 0.1 ms  (+ 1880.1 ms in 986 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 12649 ms) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
```

Is this output consistent with memory issues?

I should note that having to add this many keys to the object is an edge-case; normally the range is more likely in the thousands. In addition, the keys are added during a streaming process, so I don't know how many are required to added at the outset.  So in addition to trying to figure out what the specific problem is, I'm also looking for a way to determine that the problem will likely occur before the process hangs.

Comment: It sounds like you're running into v8's default max memory size.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8