# How to store 100GB in memory in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, out-of-memory

Say you have a machine that has 200GB+ RAM, is it possible to store that much data inside an application?

I'm running a test that creates a nested object like the following:

```
{
  id1: {
    val1: 123,
    val2: 456,
    v...
  },
  id2: {
    val1: 234,
    val2: 567,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I'll run it using `--max-old-space-size=200000` and it runs fine until the object is about 50GB in size, then crashes with error: `FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory` every time.

I've tried manually forcing garbage collection, separating it into smaller objects, etc., with no luck.

Comment: First question is "Why?" and the second question is also "Why?" I'm a big fan of Node.js but it's not the best at handling multi-GB datasets in memory. Anything beyond 1.5GB is a bit iffy even if you twiddle with `max-old-space-size` type settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8

Comment: From my experience after ~28 gigs it goes KABLAM!

Comment: This is one of the main reasons why "streaming" is in place.  You're meant to stream your data and emit chunks.  Not read a massive GB sized object into memory and then operate on it.  And if it's still some requirement to go and read such a massive object, I'd wager to say that it could likely just boil down to a major design flaw in the system.

Comment: @dvsoukup is right, you should use streams rather than loading entire data in memory, Also manually setting "max-old-space-size" is not the right choice.

Answer (score 6):

You don't.  Use streams.  The following I feel is a pretty darn good write-up of what a stream is and how to use them.  I refer to it from time to time:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

This will take your memory footprint from "200GB" for some single given object, to likely less than a few MB of memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Node doesn't do well with very large invocations, I'm surprised you're getting all the way to 50GB, I usually see crashes around 4-8GB when trying to load too much.

---

If you're working on a pipeline[1], use line-separated JSON if you're inputting/exporting to a file: (`\n` indicates end of line marker)

```
{"id":"id01',"value":{...}}\n
{"id":"id01',"value":{...}}\n
```

You can from this read/write as a stream, using already available read by row/line filters for your pipeline.

---

Alternatively, if you need this data interactively, probably best to use a local database like Redis.

[1]  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: @dvsoukup used your reference for pipeline/streams