# How can release unnecessary memory automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, memory-leaks

I built web app to display sensors and charts in real time.
it works well, but it has memory leak problem. when i start it, it took 200M memory only.
but after 10 hours, it became 2G.  I tried to fix , but seems it's from chrome browser.
when i close the chrome tab, memory was released. so I am finding to release memory automatically.
is there anyone who know this?

I noticed there is the way to restart app when memory size exceeds max size.
`pm2 start big-array.js --max-memory-restart 20M`
but it will restart app. I want to run this app without any restarting or refresh browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [memory limit in Node.js (and chrome V8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8)

Comment: for node js, the size limit it 2GB, u can set --max-old-space-size=8192 but your app will be slow down. You performance analysis , and find the exact issue.

`node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js`

Comment: if i add it, memory will be released automatically?  it will not stop the app running?
thank you

Comment: it will force GC to clean, meaning force clean. and cleaning is slow process. so it will slow down your app

Comment: yes. if it force GC to clean, web app will stop ? or it will keep to run even slow process ?
thanks :)