# How to check limit of Node heap memory size in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, memory-management

I got node heap out of memory error.

Is there any command in ubuntu to check what is the current limit of heap memory for Node.js?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8