# Storing a large tree in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory-management, heap-memory

I am testing tree search algorithms in node.js. The trees are just objects (representing nodes on the tree) that contain arrays of references to their 'child' nodes.

However, I am finding that I am often running out of memory. I've only eye-balled task manager before it crashes, but it seems to top out at 2gb.

What language features and options should I use to fix this? I know about buffers. Could I perhaps stores subtrees in multiple buffers? However a buffer is essentially an array right?

Comment: Does this help? it implies that 2G is the default limit. I assume you have a lot more than that available? https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009208393-How-can-I-increase-the-max-memory-for-Node-

Comment: More discussion here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8

Comment: thank you I think allocating more heap memory is probably the best solution

Comment: If you try this and have success, please post an answer here to help others.